# I'm getting a failed to compile error after running `npm start`

Tags: reactjs, server

I'm running a React app on localhost:3000, and trying to simultaneously run another app on localhost:3001. I've run them both individually fine before but now I'm getting an error.

`Module not found: Can't resolve './cjs/scheduler.development.js' in '/Users/sethmarks/Desktop/imagerec/node_modules/scheduler'`

What is going on? I can't run the front-end of my app now after I built the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your node_modules/ directory, and then run these commands

```
npm cache clean --force 
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. What did this do exactly?

Comment: Sometimes there might be issues when installing, upgrading or removing packages. Therefore removing all packages and then clearing the cache and installing them again fixes it most of the time. Glad I could help!